# Change touch event behaviour on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have an webpage that is essentially a family-tree built on a given div with all elements about people and connections between people done with absolute positioning inside this div. Then there is navigation bar and some buttons which should have a fixed position.

Now, the site works well with desktops where one can pan and zoom the div with the family tree around inside the browser window.

In order to make it work on mobile, I wanted to rely on touch events.
I took the recommendation of [Chris Coyer](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/touch-action/)'s site and did on my body element the following:

```
body { touch-action: none }
```

and the div with the family tree (id="container")

```
#container { touch-action : auto }
```

The aim was to freeze the normal parts of the site ( nav bar and controls) and to allow on the target div to do the pan and zoom by the touch events.

But this doesn't work at all.

Can somebody give me the deciding hint in the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

I add here the simplified code for the site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>The Nav</h4>
        </div>
         <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the styles sheet is like (simplified):

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    touch-action: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #5d4954;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

As you can see, I put the touch-action: none attribute on all elements.
But no impact at all on the site

https://rocky-refuge-29352.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Hello Jimmy, I added the minimalistic content of the site above. I used for this trial only the touch-action: none to inhibit all touch events. But no success!

Answer (score 0):

Try using specific property instead of "auto" as follows:

```
#container { touch-action: pan-x pinch-zoom; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. The site still reacts to pinch and pan as before. I first need to solve that my navbar and control buttons are fixed like the chromium.